# Pyautogui not clicking on exact location

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to get my pyautogui setup. The only code I have in it right now is to move the mouse to one location then move it to another. I am also on windows running a 2k monitor. The problem is I set the move to move to `x=1235, y=120` but the mouse actually moves to `988, 96` and when I set it to move to `x=1650, y=315` the mouse then moves to `1320, 252`. I have not found any answers for this yet. Here is the code:

(main.py)

```
import pyautogui
from mainFunctions import *
moveCharacter()
```

(mainFunctions.py)

```
import pyautogui
import time
def moveCharacter():
    pyautogui.moveTo(x=1235 , y=120)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x=1650, y=315)
```

Comment: EDIT: Program works when I set monitor to 1920x1080p but not 2560x1440p



EDIT2: Wrote a short program in autoit to click on a specific location and it does click on the specfic location @ 2560x1440p.

Comment: In that case, of course it wouldn't work. Pyautogui is very picky, and doesn't like special cases. Anyway, it looks like the rate of change is perfectly imperfect, with the value it actually goes to always 4/5 of the intended destination, so just factor this into your code. `x*=(5/4)`, `y*=(5/4)`

Answer (score 1):

That can be because of either of the two:
You change your screen resolution
OR
It's because of pyautogui's FAILSAFE system.

If you haven't changed your screen resolution, then try this code in your `mainFunctions.py` file:

```
from pyautogui import *
from time import *
def moveCharacter():
    FAILSAFE = False
    moveTo(x=1235 , y=120)
    sleep(1)
    moveTo(x=1650, y=315)
```